# update orderedDIct value by muiltplying it with by list[1]

Tags: python

```
OrderedDict([('red', 10.0),('blue',45.5),('green',34.4)]
xList[(u'blue',1.5,u'car'),(u'green',1.9,u'bike'),(u'red', 10,u'boat')]
```

How do I loop through the orderedDict and List updating the ordedDict values by mulitplying  the value by `xList[1]`?

Hope that makes sense I am struggling with this for the last few nights and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Ideally I want to get  back:

```
OrderedDict[('red',100),('blue',68.25),('green',65.36)]
```

Comment: It's just the name I gave my list.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict([('red', 10.0),('blue',45.5),('green',34.4)])
xList = [(u'blue',1.5,u'car'),(u'green',1.9,u'bike'),(u'red', 10,u'boat')]
for tup in xList: # iterate over each tuple
    if tup[0] in d: # make sure key is in the dict
        d[tup[0]] *= tup[1] # multiply current value by the second element of the tuple

print(d)

OrderedDict([('red', 100.0), ('blue', 68.25), ('green', 65.36)])
```